# RichTextBox copy issue in notepad

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, clipboard

I have used the following code to change some formatting from the text copied from a RTB on the fly using the clipboard

```
 public static void CustomCopy(RichTextBox rtb)
      {
          rtb.Copy();
          var _inMemoryRtb=new RichTextBox();
          var iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
          if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Rtf))
          {
              _inMemoryRtb.Rtf = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf);

                  _inMemoryRtb.SelectAll();
                 _inMemoryRtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                 Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, _inMemoryRtb.Rtf);


          }

          _inMemoryRtb.Clear();
      }
```

When I paste the copied text to Word/Wordpad it works but if I paste to a browser/notepad nothing happens.
Where is the issue ?

Comment: Can you please tell the exact environment you are using? I don't get SelectionUnderlineStyle as a property of the RichTextBox in winforms .NET 4.0/4.5

Comment: actually I am using a custom version of RichTextBox. Just change that any other standard RTB method and check  @varocarbas

Comment: You have to describe the exact constraints (/inputs) in order to help us to understand the problem and propose a solution. If you use a custom RTB, you should add the associated code (or you should test your conditions with the standard control and confirm/dismiss that the behaviour is the same).

Comment: There is nothing special about the custom RTB with respect to the problem cited here.Please forget about the custom RTB and change it to normal standard winform RTB. Change 'SelectionUnderlineStyle'  to SelectionBackColor and then please check the issue. @varocarbas

Comment: Got that (didn't check; just gave a generic answer: describe the input conditions properly). You cannot get what you want (RTF format to not-RTF supporting program). You would have to choose what to store in the clipboard (rtf content or the text from the richtextbox (pure text)); or come up with a "translation post-algorithm" able to deal with RTF information from text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get what you want without relying on "RTF-supporting environment", like Word. `DataFormats.Rtf` in `Clipboard.SetData` avoids any RTF-non-supporting program to not be able to deal with this data.

A `RichTextBox` and the text in it tends to be easily misundestood as text + something else, but it is a completely different format. A quick experiment to understand this better: replace in your code  `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, _inMemoryRtb.Rtf);` with `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, _inMemoryRtb.Rtf);`. What you see now is what the un-codified version of the RTF content, what any program is able to see. Bear in mind that his un-understandable text can be converted back into RTF quite easily:

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, _inMemoryRtb.Rtf);
var iData2 = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
rtb.Rtf = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
```

UPDATE

With your code, you are pasting RTF information (which cannot be dealt with by a non-RTF-supporting program, like Notepad). If you want to just paste the text in `rtb`, rely on `SetText`: you will store in the `ClipBoard` the text you want to paste (independently upon the given format) and this information will be "understood" by any program.

```
Clipboard.SetText(rtb.Text, TextDataFormat.Text);
```

CLARIFICATION

The original OP's code was copying RTF information, what cannot be understood by non-RTP-supporting programs. This code works under the right conditions (RTF supported by source and destination programs). The previous update refers to copying just text regardless of format. Thus, if what you want is to copy RTF-formatted text when possible (RichTextBox to RichTextBox) and just text otherwise (RichTextBox to Notepad), you should write both codes together (original OP's one and aforementioned `SetText`).

Comment: Ok, one thing is clear that since the clipboard data is RTF formatted then Word can understand and render it and notepad can't. but How come if I copy from word( some text with formatting) and paste to notepad it will display the text and a RTB will display the formatted text ? @varocaros

Comment: (varocarbas, but you don't need to write my nick because in my question I get the messages). You are the one who is copying/pasting as rtf; when you copy/paste text from Word by relying on RTF you would have the same problem; if you rely on the default settings you would get the standard behaviour, that is: just text if the program annot support the format or the format if the program can.

Comment: what my requirement is that if I copy from the RTB and if it has underline texts then remove it from the clipboard so that when user paste/Control+v in Word no underline should be there. how do we do that ? Actually I achieved that but if I paste in notepad nothing happens. The requirement is to change the clipboard data

Comment: @jeff you have to rely on SetText. Will update my answer now.

Comment: Ok I will try and revert

Comment: This works but if the RTB text has formatted text then formatting is gone; it is obvious. I wonder how do Word tackles this problem, i.e. if I copy formatted text from Word and paste to RTB then formatted text is pasted and if I paste to notepad then only text is pasted. Why the same can't be done in case of our situation ?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

Comment: @jeff No. If you mantain your original code the format is kept (you are copying the RTF part). The SetText suggestion was to COMPLEMENT your original code, to paste the text when RTF is not applicable. I hope that this will be enough to help you in all this out (perhaps you should describe the problems/what you want to accomplish better in future questions).

Comment: yes, it is actually very easy, I was laughing on myself. just doing  Clipboard.Clear(); _inMemoryRtb.Copy(); did the trick

Comment: I haven't misunderstood you neither I figured it out earlier. Just came to my mind. May be easy for you , but it didn't come to me earlier. I don't understand what is wrong wrong with the question ? I have stated clearly in the comments that I need to change the formatted text from clipboard.

Comment: yes I agree; the question lacked proper explanation which I tried to complement in the comments. But however it might create confusion among the readers if they don't read the whole comments. So I will mark your answer as solution because it answers the why cited in the question. Thanks varocarbas.

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't mind all these silly things. The joy of helping others and figuring out the things is much more rewarding than the vote of thanks

Comment: @jeff Don't misunderstand me. I don't care about ranking too much. I care about fairness (and fairly rewarding someone helping you). And, on top of everything, I care about feeling comfortable and doing what makes me feel better. All what I have explain intends to highlight this: if I come here to help you; I guess that your attitude (the minimum you can do) is making the process easy. Anyway... this is my opinion and this is how I behave; if you want to get help from people thinking like I do, perhaps you should bear all this in mind.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that my behavior is not-help worthy. Anyway these discussions are not going to help future readers.

Comment: @jeff you are right. I will delete all my last comments; just wanted to share them with you (PS: not saying not-help-worthy; but close to not-being too comfortable; I might have misunderstood your attitude...)

Comment: I don't understand where I went wrong in terms of attitude. I had a problem which I couldn't solve; so I put it in SO but the I couldn't explain my problem properly in the question itself which I tried to complement in the comments. You answered the question properly but not what I wanted actually( not your fault); which I somehow figured out. I wasn't laughing on you; rather myself that how silly things sometimes goes out of sight. You might have misunderstood me. Anyway I got my solution

Comment: @jeff All clear. Just clarifying that I never thought that you were laughing at me; but that you lost the main point here: generic questions/answers useful for as many people as possible. This is what makes me think that some help is worthy: if what you ask is a "serious problem" (cannot easily be found) and if the problem/solution is helpful to others. You started getting too focused on "it does work with my conditions" + asking for further (interesting just for you) help. But as said, I might have misunderstood your attitude, sorry about that.

Comment: No hard feeling, happens sometimes, I will try to be as clear as possible from next time. Sometimes when you can't figure out things yourself you become so frustrated that you put in SO; you don't think whether the question is serious or not. I can't solve it so I am asking SO. that's it. Thanks for clarification and discussion.